How to capture a screenshot even if app has not allowing to capture screenshot
So there are many apps which do not allow to take screenshots on their app and they have restricted to capture a screenshot and whenever we use the screen share app from play store , the app doesn't work it says someone is trying to steal money form your bank account, without root.
